# PouchDB return 404 on design docucment even if this document exist

Tags: nosql, couchdb, pouchdb

This command ...

```
this._db.query(`classRoom_ZSFtmZiBu/robots`, {
    classRoomCode: this.classRoomCode,
}).then(res => res.rows.map(it => it.key));
```

Throw 404 error ...

[image]

Even if the design document exist on database ..

[image]

```
  "_id": "_design/classRoom_ZSFtmZiBu",
  "_rev": "1-667891751ba8a733dc1976172de9b513",
  "views": {
    "robots": {
      "map": "function (doc) {\n                if (doc.type === \"robot\") {\n                  emit(doc);\n                }\n              }"
    }
  },
  "filters": {
    "robotsOnThisClassRoomOnly": "function (doc, req) {\n              return doc.type === \"robot\" && doc.classRoom === req.query.classRoomCode;\n            }"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't reproduce your issue. I use CouchDB 2.1

The following is my screenshots.

[image]

I have two documents, one of which is a design document same as yours.

[image]

[image]

Now I query using CouchDB in the browser.
[image]

This is the query result on the dev console.

[image]

Comment: I will try change the version.. I'm using Fauxton on Apache CouchDB 1.6.1

Comment: Are you using MAC?  Did you test on localhost or over  IP/domain?
In my machine... only when I use IP address that this error occurs

Comment: OK. I will try the IP